# error in implementation of bucket sort

Tags: c++, sorting, data-structures, bucket

here is my code from which can't understand where is error

```
#include <iostream>
#include<iomanip>
using namespace std;
#define narray 8;// array size;
#define  nbucket 5;// bucket size;
#define interval 10;// bucket range
struct node
{
int data;
struct node *next;
};
void BucketSort(int arr[]);
struct node *InsertionSort(struct Node *list);
void print(int arr[]);
void printBuckets(struct Node *list);
int getBucketIndex(int value);
void BucketSort(int arr[])
{

 int i,j;
 struct node **buckets;
 buckets = (struct node **)malloc(sizeof(struct node*) * nbucket); 
 for (i=0;i<nbucket;i++){
      buckets[i]=NULL;
 }
 for (int i=0;i<narray;i++){
  struct node *current;
  int pos=getBucketIndex(arr[i]);
  current=(struct node *)malloc(sizeof(struct node));
  current->data=arr[i];
  current->next=buckets[pos];
  buckets[pos]=current;


 }

}


int main(){





 return 0;
}
```

errors  are a lot of,for example

```
Error   1   error C2143: syntax error : missing ')' before ';'  c:\documents and settings\student\my documents\visual studio 2008\projects\bucket_sort\bucket_sort\bucket_sort.cpp  22  bucket_sort
Error   2   error C2059: syntax error : ')' c:\documents and settings\student\my documents\visual studio 2008\projects\bucket_sort\bucket_sort\bucket_sort.cpp  22  bucket_sort
Error   3   error C2146: syntax error : missing ')' before identifier 'i'   c:\documents and settings\student\my documents\visual studio 2008\projects\bucket_sort\bucket_sort\bucket_sort.cpp  23  bucket_sort
Error   4   error C2059: syntax error : ';' c:\documents and settings\student\my documents\visual studio 2008\projects\bucket_sort\bucket_sort\bucket_sort.cpp  23  bucket_sort
Error   5   error C2059: syntax error : ')' c:\documents and settings\student\my documents\visual studio 2008\projects\bucket_sort\bucket_sort\bucket_sort.cpp  23  bucket_sort
Error   6   error C2143: syntax error : missing ';' before '{'  c:\documents and settings\student\my documents\visual studio 2008\projects\bucket_sort\bucket_sort\bucket_sort.cpp  23  bucket_sort
Error   7   error C2146: syntax error : missing ')' before identifier 'i'   c:\documents and settings\student\my documents\visual studio 2008\projects\bucket_sort\bucket_sort\bucket_sort.cpp  26  bucket_sort
Error   8   error C2059: syntax error : ';' c:\documents and settings\student\my documents\visual studio 2008\projects\bucket_sort\bucket_sort\bucket_sort.cpp  26  bucket_sort
Error   9   error C2059: syntax error : ')' c:\documents and settings\student\my documents\visual studio 2008\projects\bucket_sort\bucket_sort\bucket_sort.cpp  26  bucket_sort
Error   10  error C2143: syntax error : missing ';' before '{'  c:\documents and settings\student\my documents\visual studio 2008\projects\bucket_sort\bucket_sort\bucket_sort.cpp  26  bucket_sort
```

Comment: Regretfully I did not use Stackoverflow when it was the time of the 15 pages long errors when using templates. Otherwise I could have stuck the site with compilation error logs.

Comment: atleast try to follow compiler instructions in debugging before asking for help

Comment: One extra comment before your question gets down-voted into oblivion: This is C++, so lose the surplus "struct" keywords. You need "struct" to declare the structure, but after that refer to it as `node`, `node*`, `node**` rather than `struct node*`, `struct node**`

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Remove the `;` from `#define  nbucket 5;` and the other defines.

At the moment, line 22 is expanded by the preprocessor to become the obviously-invalid:

```
buckets = (struct node **)malloc(sizeof(struct node*) * 5;);
//                                                      ^^
```

Comment: thanks  @Henrik but it could be done without downvoting think

Comment: Furthermore, lose the #defines altogether. Prefer `const int nbucket = 5;`

Answer (score 0):

The `#define` lines are *not* part of the compiler, it's part of a [*pre processor*](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/C_preprocessor) that runs before the compiler. The lines handled by the pre-processor should not be terminated with semicolon.

Take for example this line:

```
#define narray 8;// array size;
```

This creates a *macro* named `narray`. When the pre-processor runs it replaces all instances of `narray` with the replacement text, in this case `8;`. As you can see, having `8;` inside an expression will add a semicolon where there shouldn't be any.